# What's the correct way of returning HTTP error codes in serverless lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a serverless lambda function written in Node.JS.

**What is the best / correct way of returning error codes?**

The pattern that I use right now (**and it works!**) is:

```
module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 404,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello World!' })
    };
    callback(null, response);
}
```

When I make a call, for example from POSTMAN, to my endpoint I get:

`Status: 404 Not Found`  which **is exactly what I'm expecting**.

Moreover, in the logs I can see:

```
Serverless: GET / (λ: get)
Serverless: [404] {"statusCode":404,"body":"{\"message\":\"Hello World!\"}"}
```

That works well.

What bothers me is that I'm passing `null` as the error. Looking into a few other tutorials/examples I've found patterns like:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/

`callback ("the sky is falling!");`

`callback("[BadRequest] Validation error: Missing field 'name'");`

`callback("[404] Not Found");`

`callback(new Error('[404] Not found'));`

`callback(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));`

All of them make perfect sense and you can specify HTTP Status Code - yet what I'm getting is HTTP Status Code 200 in the end. When I look at the logs I can see that the error was followed straight after with 200:

```
Serverless: GET / (λ: get)
Serverless: Failure: the sky is falling!
Serverless: Replying 200

Serverless: GET / (λ: get)
Serverless: Failure: [BadRequest] Validation error: Missing field 'name'
Serverless: Replying 200

Serverless: GET / (λ: get)
Serverless: Failure: [404] Not Found
Serverless: Replying 200

Serverless: GET / (λ: get)
Serverless: Failure: [404] Not found
Serverless: Replying 200

Serverless: GET / (λ: get)
Serverless: Failure: {"errorType":"InternalServerError","httpStatus":500,"message":"An unknown error has occurred. Please try again."}
Serverless: Replying 200
```

In this place I've found following explanation:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4119

> If you want to respond with HTTP errors in that case, you have to
>   encode the HTTP error as successful Lambda response

with following example:

```
Sample 403:
callback(null, { statusCode: 403, body: "Forbidden", headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } });
Sample 404:
callback(null, { statusCode: 400 });
```

So that's basically the same way I've. For the sake of completeness, I can add that there is also a plenty of examples that uses `context.fail(result)` or `context.succeed(result)` - but from what I gathered `context` is deprecated and shouldn't be used (even though it still works).

What is the point of using `callback(error)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If you want to respond with HTTP errors in that case, you have to encode the HTTP error as successful Lambda response

This type of error-handling is specific to API Gateway.

Just like in traditional Node web servers (e.g. express), you can throw any error using `throw new Error('Invalid Payload')` and the middleware usually converts it into an HTTP response with the correct response status.

In API Gateway Lambda, this can be written like this...

```
function createResponse(status, body) {
  return {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    statusCode: status,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}

module.exports.endpoint = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
      return callback(null, createResponse(200, processEvent(event)))
    } except (e) {
      console.error(e)

      return callback(null, createResponse(500, {
        error: 'Internal Server Error'
      }))
    }
}
```

Basically, it's a handled error. The lambda function succeeded but the request failed (maybe 400, 404, or 500).

You should be handling errors always, or else if your handler crashes (due to a runtime error or syntax error or any unhandled error), your user will get an unexpected response (a 500 or a 502) which you probably don't want.

---

Please remember that Lambda is not only used for API Gateway. `callback(error)` is used for non-API Gateway-triggered Lambdas.

For example, if you have an SNS-triggered Lambda, you can return `callback('Any error message here')` and it will let SNS know that it failed and so SNS can retry the invocation.

Comment: I see that you are using the same way in the end: `return callback(null, createResponse)` - pass `null` as error and then actual error goes to result.

Comment: Yes. As I said, you should handle errors for API Gateway Lambdas.

Comment: @iaforek What are you still confused with?

Comment: I’m not confused. Just a bit disappointed with the way errors are handled and documentation behind it.

Comment: @iaforek How would you want the errors to be handled then?

Comment: It's not about how I would like to handled them. It's about that when you got through documentation and examples it's not clear and is misleading IMHO.

Comment: @iaforek That's AWS for you. :-)

Comment: @iaforek I agree that the docs are confusing, but it makes sense the way dashmug describes it in context of the API gateway. This is very helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the function was called from API gateway or another trigger? It seems odd to have to write a function that knows who called it in the first place.

Comment: @Juvaly That's a good question that deserves more than a comment. Would you mind creating that as a question in StackOverflow?

Comment: Is this answer valid anymore? I'm using node.js 8.* version and nothing actually changes the response of the api gateway, its always 200.  UPDATE: i figured out that schemas and error codes needs to be configured in the gateway section, not lambdas part. which is really confusing!